# Nuxt 3 button on click login only works first time

Tags: nuxt3

If i fill in wrong login details I get back an error and nothing happens, which is fine. When I fill in correct login details (after filling in bad ones), i keep getting a error returned.

Logging in works only when I use the correct details the first time.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

```
<button @click="save" type="button" class="flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-red-600 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-grey-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-grey-600">
     {{ $t('login') }}
</button>

const save = async () => {
  let { data, pending, error } = await useFetch('https://mywebsite/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: email.value })
  })

  if (data.value) {
    cookie.value = JSON.parse(data.value).token
    window.location.href = '/formulier'
  }
}
```

Am unable to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: have you check the developer tools console for errors?

Comment: May be your API request is failed

Comment: I updated my question, I wasn't clear enough sorry.